# Добавить готовую анимацию в Blender

Tags: анимация, 3d, blender

Есть две модели с сайта mixamo.com с разными анимациями. Можно ли из одной модели добавить анимацию в другую, чтобы в итоге модель имела две анимации?

[image: Модели в Blender]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не буду расписывать всю последовательность, но у меня есть [ускоренное видео этого процесса](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq3uFKAY2a4) с момента загрузки модели c mixamo.com до связывания с анимацией в Blender.

Comment: Ссылку поправил. Видео старое, но моё. Походу могут быть различия в интерфейсе с текущей версией blender и ранним доступом к mixamo, но суть остается прежней - модель забрасывается на mixamo, связывается с выбранной арматурой, выбираются требуемая анимация, скачивается к себе, анимации добавляются в blender и через DopeSheet Action Editor делается привязка полисетки к добавленной анимации (это начинается с 50 секунды).

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает.